# cómo hacer que queden

Tags: traducción

Question: Is using the word "quedar" (to be left/remain) like this a common way of talking of the weight of something? I seen this phrase in an interactive video I'm using while studying Spanish.

[Español]
Cómo hacer que queden de cien gramos las tortas.

[Inglés]
how to make the cakes of one hundred grams.

Comment: How to make cakes so they weigh 100 grams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, "quedar" is used to refer to a result, approximately meaning "turn out to be": how to make cakes so that they end up having a weight of 100 grams (after the process of preparation/cooking).

The meaning under [DRAE](https://dle.rae.es/quedar) that in my view best conveys this idea is:

> 6. intr. Cesar, terminar, acabar. Quedó aquí la conversación. Quedamos conformes.
>    Sin.: acabar, terminar.

I think [this site](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/quedar) provides a better definition and example, more in line with the one in question:

> 7 Resultar Ejemplo: Este plato que preparé **quedó** buenísimo.